# What are alternetives to Object destructuring in Dart?

Tags: json, dart

If you had a JSON-encoded response ...

You can print a list of records in javascript like this...

```js
const doc = {
  record: [
    {id: 3},
    {id: 5},
  ],
  metadata: {
    id: "test",
  },
};
//The destructuring assignment also works with objects in javascript
const {
  record: r,
  metadata: m
} = doc;

const list = r.map(rec => rec.id);

console.log(list);
```

#### How do I split a JSON object then create a list of values using Dart?

Comment: `doc` in your Dart example is not a `JSON` string. Also, the code is not valid since `record` and `metadata` is just variable names which does not exists in your code.

Comment: OK I have removed dart code

Comment: Dart does not have any concept of destructuring like the showed JavaScript example. You will need to go through the `Map` object and extract the information manually using loops. There are some (old) discussion about a feature here: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Dart 3.0+

In Dart 3 records and [pattern](https://dart.dev/language/patterns) matching were introduced, you can use it to destructure your JSON as follows (I took freedom to consider your JSON object as a Map in Dart):

```dart
void main() {
  final doc = {
    'record': [
      {'id': 3},
      {'id': 5},
    ],
    'metadata': {
      'id': "test",
    },
  };

  // Or 'var' if you want to reasign these variables
  final {
    'record': [
      recordId3,
      recordId5,
      ...
    ] as List, // the "..." is used to create a pattern that matches a list with two or more entries. Without the "..." the pattern would match a list with two entries only.
    'metadata': {'id': metadataId as String} as Map,
  } = doc;

  print(recordId3);
  print(recordId5);
  print(metadataId);
}
```

Please remember that this will throw a `StateError('Bad state: Pattern matching error')` if the Map object (JSON in JavaScript terms) doesn't follow the pattern described, so it's risk to use, to check if the pattern match before destructuring it you can use `if case` statement:

```dart
void main() {
  final doc = {
    'record': [
      {'id': 3},
      // Try uncommenting to make it work again.
      // {'id': 5},
    ],
    'metadata': {
      'id': 'test',
    },
  };

  /// obs 1. You can make it even more specific by applying nested patterns.
  ///
  /// obs 2. When you are writing a match, remember to use 'ClassName()' instead of 'ClassName',
  /// in this example it's 'Map()', not simply 'Map'. 'Map' will match actually the Dart core 'Type' class == 'Map'.
  ///
  /// obs 3. You can use 'as' to cast the variable to a specific type.
  if (doc case {'record': [Map(/**  length: 1 */), Map()], 'metadata': Map()}) {
    // Or 'var' if you want to reasign these variables
    final {
      'record': [
        recordId3,
        recordId5,
        ...
      ] as List, // the "..." is used to create a pattern that matches a list with two or more entries. Without the "..." the pattern would match a list with two entries only.
      'metadata': {'id': metadataId as String} as Map,
    } = doc;

    print(recordId3);
    print(recordId5);
    print(metadataId);
  } else {
    print('JSON did not matcht!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using [Patterns](https://dart.dev/language/patterns) _?

Comment: Yes, added the link

Comment: The  answer could be improved by amending the comment: `// the ... is important to ignore any other elements that might be in the list` to something like: `// the ... is used to create a pattern that matches a list with two or more entries`. Without the `...` the pattern would match a list with two entries only.

Comment: Agreed, updated.

Comment: Why doesn't this simply work? https://dart.dev/language/patterns#destructuring-class-instances